# Check for null values in an object

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am new to typescript and I was wondering if there is a more efficient way to check for null values in an object besides using a for loop? Example below:

```
interface testType {
    one: string | null;
    two: string | null;
    three: string | null;
    four: string | null;
}

const dict: testType = {
    one: "hello",
    two: "world",
    three: null,
    four: "!",
};

let field: keyof testType;
for (field in dict) {
    if (dict[field] == null) {
        console.log('null');
    } else {
        console.log('exist');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`Object.values()` and `some()` will combine nicely to do it...

```
Object.values(testType).some(value => value === null)
```

Docs: [Object.values()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) and [some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

Comment: Note: this is a better looking solution, but it is not more **efficient**. In fact, it is impossible to perform this task more **efficiently**, since you have to check *each* element of your collection. Hence, the best possible time complexity is linear O(n).

Comment: @Akmal-threepointsix - the OP might have meant "concise" (efficient to code) as opposed to referring to complexity.  For what it's worth, this will run on average half as many iterations than the OP's for loop, or `.every()`, though, at the scale of 4 object entries, it's all in the noise.

Answer (score 0):

[every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) works too. You can increase solutions with standard built-in methods.

```
const isNull = Object.values(object).every(x => (x === null || x === ''));
```

Answer (score 0):

Iteration is required in this scenario, so some kind of "loop" is the only way to check each value.

The only type-safe way to iterate the **expected** keys (or values at the expected keys) in an object in TypeScript is to maintain a list of the keys and use them for iteration. In the example below, I use an array of keys (initialized with a [`const` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions)) along with the type utility [`Record<Keys, Type>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeys-type) to build the type of the interface in your question. Then the array of keys is used to iterate the object annotated by the same type:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/MYewdgzgLgBA1gUwJ4RgXhgbQOTgdgGhmygHcRDioALAJwXyOwDMQBXW7AXRgENVQkKAG4AUKKhIADghgARAJbAoAaWToYkmSGbxkETGDYBbAEYJaXMTBsB6WwD0A-OK2zFyjQCUEoWgBMAHg9VZCJoWgUwAHMYAB8YIwAbJIA+MVsAKhsYBxgAFWoFVDcYJJAQOFQkhUQALglpdyVYDABvURs8OpgIqNiE5KTrTXIevpj4xLYUkZp6BHGoSMnBmeHOmFYOJZWB6dnRAF9RTNtxJIRYfxaekI0OrrBFmAAiagQUkFeCTbIQHqvci0JL+H5-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-g6nJMjECE2CypsAByVlRLZ2q9EB+YcLIaEYbwMBSLwtC8DxUAWNp9myHpeyyaQEnbDZhJgLFjktM5WIAOwAAwAKwAMxkmcxw4SAmI4u6NI5rIRIAPKmAAVr4UCyqGEBYiRpFSu6nreoqoZmpBtgwAWUXhVACjUp8BIKqgCC8MA1AwBRRGvEun5ZnVf5FqW5aVtWtb1i0rzHEAA)

```ts
const keys = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four'] as const;

type DictKey = typeof keys[number];
   //^? type DictKey = "one" | "two" | "three" | "four"

type Dict = Record<DictKey, string | null>;
/*   ^ This type looks like:
type Dict = {
  one: string | null;
  two: string | null;
  three: string | null;
  four: string | null;
}
*/

let dict: Dict = {
  one: "hello",
  two: "world",
  three: null,
  four: "!",
};

for (const key of keys) {
  const value = dict[key];
  if (typeof value === 'string') {
    console.log(`${key} exists:`, value);
                                //^? const value: string
  } else {
    console.log(`${key} is ${value}`);
                           //^? const value: null
  }
}
```

The reason for this is that TypeScript is [structurally-typed](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes-func.html#structural-typing), so it allows for extra (excess) properties in object values assigned to an object type — as long as all the expected properties are there and their values are of the correct type.

```ts
const anotherValueThatIsAssignableToDict = {
  one: 'goodnight',
  two: 'moon',
  three: null,
  four: null,
  booleanProp: false,
  numberProp: 22,
  stringProp: 'unexpected',
};

dict = anotherValueThatIsAssignableToDict; // TypeScript is ok with this
```

Trying to iterate the keys of an object type using `key in object` or `Object.keys` will always result in `string` key types:

```ts
for (const key in dict) {
  const value = dict[key]; /*
                ~~~~~~~~~
  Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'Dict'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'Dict'.(7053) */
}
```

And, if you simply iterate the values in the object (like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73377607/438273)), you'll get all of the excess values, too, which is very unlikely what you want:

```ts
for (const value of Object.values(dict)) {
  console.log(value); // Iteratively logs each value in "anotherValueThatIsAssignableToDict"
}
```

So, maintaining a list of the keys yourself is the only type-safe way, and it is also more performant because it skips iterating the excess entries in the object.